# How to bind a list of custom objects to a chart

Tags: c#, charts

I have a list of objects like this:

```
public class Result
{
    public decimal Errors { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public Result(decimal errors, DateTime date)
    {
        this.Errors = errors;
        this.Date = date;
    }
}
```

I want to bind it to a chart, where Date is on X and Errors is on Y.

The chart should look like this:

[image]

This is what I did so far:

```
chartStats.Series.Clear();
        List<decimal> yValues = new List<decimal>();
        List<DateTime> xValues = new List<DateTime>();
        foreach (var item in Data.List)
        {
            yValues.Add(item.Errors);
            xValues.Add(item.Date);
        }
        var series = new Series()
        {
            ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column,
            IsVisibleInLegend = false
        };
        chartStats.Series.Add(series);
        chartStats.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(xValues, yValues);
```

How am I supposed to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried?  What specifically is not working for you?  This is not a code writing service, you have to show _some_ effort...

Comment: Sure I tried, but I didn't think it was rilevant due it's not working. I'll edit my post

Comment: @AlessioRaddi But if you provided the code you had so far would mean someone could guide you in the right direction as well, not just provide a working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out another way to do what I wanted.

I've edited some code used in a previous project:

```
        chartStats.Series.Clear();
        var series1 = new Series
        {
            Name = "Series1",
            Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green,
            IsVisibleInLegend = false,
            IsXValueIndexed = true,
            ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column,
            XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime
        };

        chartStats.Series.Add(series1);

        foreach(var result in Data.List)
        {
            series1.Points.AddXY(result.Date, result.Errors);
        }
        chartStats.Invalidate();
```

Had some problems with DateTime, but I added the `XValueType` in the `Series`.

Thank you all for the help.